# Finding a file in zipentry java

Tags: java, zipinputstream

I am trying to find a file within a zip file and get it as an `InputStream`. So this is what I am doing to get it so far and I am not certain if I am doing it correctly.

Here is a sample as the original is slightly longer but this is the main component...

```
public InputStream Search_Image(String file_located, ZipInputStream zip) 
    throws IOException {
    for (ZipEntry zip_e = zip.getNextEntry(); zip_e != null ; zip_e = zip.getNextEntry()) {
        if (file_located.equals(zip_e.getName())) {
            return zip;
        }
        if (zip_e.isDirectory()) {
            Search_Image(file_located, zip); 
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now the main problem I am facing is that The `ZipInputStream` in `Search_Image` is the same as the original component of the `ZipInputStream`...

```
if(zip_e.isDirectory()) {
    //"zip" is the same as the original I need a change here to find folders again.
    Search_Image(file_located, zip); 
}
```

Now for the question, how do you get the `ZipInputStream` as the new `zip_entry`? Also please add in if I did anything wrong in my method as my logic with this class is still lacking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the class `ZipFile` without worrying yourself with an input stream if you don't need it yet.

```
ZipFile file = new ZipFile("file.zip");
ZipInputStream zis = searchImage("foo.png", file);

public InputStream searchImage(String name, ZipFile file) {
  for (ZipEntry e : Collections.list(file.entries())) {
    if (e.getName().endsWith(name)) {
      return file.getInputStream(e);
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Some facts:

- you should follow conventions for naming methods and variables in your code (`Search_Image` is not fine, `searchImage` is)
- directories in zip files does not contain any file, they are just entries like everything else so you shouldn't try to recurse into them)
- you should compare the name you provide by using `endsWith(name)` because the file could be inside a folder and a filename inside a zip always contains the path

Comment: What happens when the image I seek is in a folder with the zip?. I had this as my original method problem was that this doesn't search the directories for the image.

Comment: because you were using `equals(..)` instead that `endsWith(..)`, take a look at my third point.

Answer (score 5):

Accessing to a zip entry using `ZipInputStream` is clearly not the way to do it as you will need to iterate over the entries to find it which **is not a scalable approach** because the performance will depend on total amount of entries in your zip file.

To get the best possible performances, you need to use a [`ZipFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) in order to **access directly to an entry** thanks to the method [`getEntry(name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getEntry-java.lang.String-) whatever the size of your archive.

```
public InputStream searchImage(String name, ZipFile zipFile) throws IOException {
    // Get the entry by its name
    ZipEntry entry = zipFile.getEntry(name);
    if (entry != null) {
        // The entry could be found
        return zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
    }
    // The entry could not be found
    return null;
}
```

Please note that the name to provide here is **the relative path of your image** in the archive using `/` as path separator so if you want to access to `foo.png` that is in the directory `bar`, the expected name will be `bar/foo.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(new File("/path/to/zip/file.zip"));
InputStream inputStream = searchWithinZipArchive("findMe.txt", zipFile);

public InputStream searchWithinZipArchive(String name, ZipFile file) throws Exception {
  Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = file.entries();
  while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
     ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
      if(zipEntry.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(name)){
             return file.getInputStream(zipEntry);
      }
  }
  return null;
}
```