# Getting specific file from ZipInputStream

Tags: java, file-io, groovy, inputstream, zipinputstream

I can go through `ZipInputStream`, but before starting the iteration I want to get a specific file that I need during the iteration. How can I do that?

```
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(myInputStream)
while ((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null)
 {
    println entry.getName()
}
```

Comment: I don't understand...  Iterate the entries till you get the one you want, then process it?

Comment: First iterate to the file and store it the way you want. Then just iterate again.

Comment: There is also ZipFile (java < 7) and the Zip Filesystem starting from Java7 (although not possible from a ZipInputStream :)), that's why this is not an answer to the question

Comment: tim_yates: the file in question is necessary for processing the other files. So if the first iteration the file is not what I want, I could no longer process it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `myInputStream` you're working with comes from a real file on disk then you can simply use `java.util.zip.ZipFile` instead, which is backed by a `RandomAccessFile` and provides direct access to the zip entries by name.  But if all you have is an `InputStream` (e.g. if you're processing the stream directly on receipt from a network socket or similar) then you'll have to do your own buffering.

You could copy the stream to a temporary file, then open that file using `ZipFile`, or if you know the maximum size of the data in advance (e.g. for an HTTP request that declares its `Content-Length` up front) you could use a `BufferedInputStream` to buffer it in memory until you've found the required entry.

```
BufferedInputStream bufIn = new BufferedInputStream(myInputStream);
bufIn.mark(contentLength);
ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(bufIn);
boolean foundSpecial = false;
while ((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
  if("special.txt".equals(entry.getName())) {
    // do whatever you need with the special entry
    foundSpecial = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(foundSpecial) {
  // rewind
  bufIn.reset();
  zipIn = new ZipInputStream(bufIn);
  // ....
}
```

(I haven't tested this code myself, you may find it's necessary to use something like the commons-io `CloseShieldInputStream` in between the `bufIn` and the first `zipIn`, to allow the first zip stream to close without closing the underlying `bufIn` before you've rewound it).

Answer (score 5):

use the getName() method on ZipEntry to get the file you want.

```
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(myInputStream)
String myFile = "foo.txt";
while ((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null)
{
    if (entry.getName().equals(myFileName)) {
        // process your file
        // stop looking for your file - you've already found it
        break;
    }
}
```

From Java 7 onwards, you are better off using ZipFile instead of ZipStream if you only want one file and you have a file to read from:

```
ZipFile zfile = new ZipFile(aFile);
String myFile = "foo.txt";
ZipEntry entry = zfile.getEntry(myFile);
if (entry) {
     // process your file           
}
```

Comment: For your first code: see my response to tim_yates.
For your seconde code: I thought there was something similar to ZipFile. So for my case should use ZipFile.

Comment: but HOW to process the file? What you show is the trivial part: getting the entry, but how to get the data of that specific entry?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Finding a file in zip entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123528/finding-a-file-in-zipentry-java)

```
ZipFile file = new ZipFile("file.zip");
ZipInputStream zis = searchImage("foo.png", file);

public searchImage(String name, ZipFile file)
{
  for (ZipEntry e : file.entries){
    if (e.getName().endsWith(name)){
      return file.getInputStream(e);
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: The method 'searchImage' is missing the return type 'ZipInputStream'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but all above "answers" does not answer the question and accepted "answer" suggest create temp file which is inefficient.

Lets create sample zip file:

```
seq 10000 | sed "s/^.*$/a/"> /tmp/a
seq 10000 20000 | sed "s/^.*$/b/"> /tmp/b
seq 20000 30000 | sed "s/^.*$/c/"> /tmp/c
zip /tmp/out.zip /tmp/a /tmp/b /tmp/c
```

so now we have `/tmp/out.zip` file, which contains 3 files, each of them full of chars a, b or c.

Now lets read it:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("/tmp/out.zip"));
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            while ((zipEntry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                String name = zipEntry.getName();
                System.out.println("Entry: "+name);
                if (name.equals("tmp/c")) {
                    byte[] bytes = zipStream.readAllBytes();
                    String s = new String(bytes);
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
    }
```

method `readAllBytes` seems weird, while we're in processing of stream, but it seems to work, I tested it also on some images, where there is higher chance of failure. So it's probably just unintuitive api, but it seems to work.

Comment: Sorry, "seems to work" is not something I will ever use.